# C#: access variable in the inner scope from the outer scope

Tags: c#, while-loop

I'm creating an instance of a class inside a while loop - I need the while loop to get the input arguments i need to create the instance (I have to read it in from an extern file). But then I would like to have access to the instance from outside the loop. Is there a possibility?

```
public static <class> leseProjektDatei()
{

while ((zeile = datei.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine(zeile);
           string id, wetterdatei, fruchtfolge, bodenprofil, grundwasser;
           id = zeile.Substring(0, 5);
           wetterdatei = zeile.Substring(7, 14);
           fruchtfolge = zeile.Substring(22, 14);
           bodenprofil = zeile.Substring(37, 14);


           <class> projekt = new <class>(id, wetterdatei, fruchtfolge, bodenprofil);

            } 
 return <class>
}
```

Comment: is there one instance or multiple instance?

Comment: Is this supposed to be C#? `<class>`?

Comment: <Class> is just the place holder for the name of the class

Comment: Aniket: just one instance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes do it like this:

```
public class Project{
    public string id{get;set;} 
    public string wetterdatei{get;set;}
    public string fruchtfolge {get;set;} 
    public string bodenprofil {get;set;} 
}


public static Project leseProjektDatei(){
Project projekt = new Project();
while ((zeile = datei.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
           projekt.id = zeile.Substring(0, 5);
           projekt.wetterdatei = zeile.Substring(7, 14);
           projekt.fruchtfolge = zeile.Substring(22, 14);
           projekt.bodenprofil = zeile.Substring(37, 14);

             } 
return projekt;
}
```

Name the class anyway you would like.

Comment: I can't do    Project projekt = new Project()    because the input arguments are missing ;)

Comment: Huh, what do you mean? If you make a Class Project it should work. (I tried it out, my code works.)

Answer (score 1):

You can not retrive it outside of the loop, try delcaring it out of the loop and then you will be able to access it.

```
public static <class> leseProjektDatei()
{
 <class> projekt;
while ((zeile = datei.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine(zeile);
           string id, wetterdatei, fruchtfolge, bodenprofil, grundwasser;
           id = zeile.Substring(0, 5);
           wetterdatei = zeile.Substring(7, 14);
           fruchtfolge = zeile.Substring(22, 14);
           bodenprofil = zeile.Substring(37, 14);


            projekt = new <class>(id, wetterdatei, fruchtfolge, bodenprofil);

            } 
 return projekt;
}
```

Comment: No,    return <class>    has an error "Verwendung der nicht zugewiesenen lokalen Variable "projekt"", what means: use of unassigned local variable!

Comment: use `return projekt;`, i have edited my answer, sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need a `List` of `YourClass` objects, for which the following code should work:

```
public static IEnumerable<YourClass> leseProjektDatei()
{
var list = new List<YourClass>();
while ((zeile = datei.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine(zeile);
           string id, wetterdatei, fruchtfolge, bodenprofil, grundwasser;
           id = zeile.Substring(0, 5);
           wetterdatei = zeile.Substring(7, 14);
           fruchtfolge = zeile.Substring(22, 14);
           bodenprofil = zeile.Substring(37, 14);


           list.Add(new YourClass(id, wetterdatei, fruchtfolge, bodenprofil));

       } 
return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `List<class>` and add newly created instances of `class` to it in the while loop. Afterwards every created class is stored and can be accessed?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot retrieve the object outside of the while loop. One way around this is to add the object to an array that was declared outside of the loop, during the loop and returning the value of that array. This is assuming you want to create a new object with every iteration of the while loop. But due to your implementation it is unclear.