# C# Access datatable from outer scope

Tags: c#, json, while-loop, datatable, scope

I have JSON files with 2 objects... for this example "Country" and "Data". I'm trying to deserialize the "Data" object into datatable "sortedFileData" but have been unable to access the datatable from inside the while loop. I've found how to solve if creating a new class ([C#: access variable in the inner scope from the outer scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25802195/c-access-variable-in-the-inner-scope-from-the-outer-scope) ) but I won't be doing that here.

```
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(selectedProject, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
        using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            DataTable sortedFileData = new DataTable();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                {
                    // Load each object from the stream and do something with it
                    JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show((string)obj["Country"]);
                    DataTable sortedFileData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>((string)obj["Data"]);
                }
            }
        }

        string sorted = "Name ASC, Age ASC, Date ASC";
        DataView dtView = new DataView(sortedFileData) {Sort = sorted};
```

Sample JSON:

```js
 {
  "Country": "England",
  "Data": [
    {
      "Name": "Bill",
      "Age": "70",
      "Date": "2015-05-27"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Sara",
      "Age": "36",
      "Date": "2015-01-21"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Bob",
      "Age": "7",
      "Date": "2011-05-24"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can create a `List<DataTable>` outside the while loop (perhaps near/instead of `DataTable sortedPlotFileData = new DataTable();`) and add to this table inside the while loop?

Comment: Could you please elaborate the question? Are you trying to desalinize `sortedPlotFileData`   to `sortedFileData` ?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. I edited the question above to correct it & simplify the example further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare it outside of the loops and assign it in the same place.

```
    DataTable sortedFileData;

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(selectedProject, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
            {
                // Load each object from the stream and do something with it
                JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show((string)obj["Country"]);
                sortedFileData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>((string)obj["DataTable1"]);
            }
        }
    }

    string sorted = "Name ASC, Age ASC, Date ASC";
    if (sortedFileData != null) 
    {
        DataView dtView = new DataView(sortedFileData) {Sort = sorted};
    }
```

And then you can just do a quick null check to make sure that everything went as expected.

Comment: Thanks so much, this did the trick!   For anybody who may be looking to do this.... I do want to add: <DataTable>((string)obj["DataTable1"]); kept giving me the error "cannot convert array to string" so I had to change it to  <DataTable>(obj["DataTable1"].ToString())